# Required email input remains in invalid state when autocomplete in Firefox

Tags: html, validation, firefox, browser

I have been searching for this but there does not seem to be any clear related issues to this problem.

In Firefox, a required email input, when auto completed (in my understanding of the word, the user selected from the suggestions from the browser), does not seem to revalidate and remains in `:invalid` state.

[image: firstly typed, incomplete email address: invalid state]

[image: selected email address from suggestions: remains invalid]

This is the code for the input (nothing fancy):

`<input id="email" name="email" type="email" required/>`

There is some JS applied to the input, but it still fails to revalidate if I remove it.

It works fine in webkit.
It works ok in Firefox for say a `text` input with `pattern` attribute.

Is this a known bug (I couldn't find anything closely related)? 
Is there a workaround (I tried to manually call `reportValidity` on `input` event, but that didn't change anything)? I would like to avoid using a specific `is-invalid` class and actually rely on the browser as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a Mozilla bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1539172